# Writing to a file with file class

Tags: c#-4.0

I try to create code that creates a file and writes a user name and password to the file. When I try to run the code it keeps telling me that the file is already use and I can't change the file. Can someone can tell me what the problem with my code is?

```
string FileName = @"C:\project\userandPassword.txt";
StreamWriter RW = new StreamWriter(FileName); 

UserName user = new UserName();
if (File.Exists(FileName))
{
    // delete the file if exists
    File.Delete(FileName);
}
else
{
    // if doesn't, it will create.
    File.Create(FileName);
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your new user name");
    user.Newuser = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your password");
    user.Newpassword = Console.ReadLine();
    RW.WriteLine(user.Newuser);
    RW.WriteLine(user.Newpassword);
    RW.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question and include the exact error message you are getting (including line numbers or stack traces, if any).

Comment: As a side note, you should never save passwords in plain. It's extremely insecure, and punishable under GDPR. Always save salted hashes instead. Or use a library that does this for you. Another thing: please provide code as a [mcve]. I tried to format your code, but it's not clear if that `if` and `else` are supposed to be that way: if the file exists you'd only delete it, but not write it --- is this intended? Just for code clarity you could move the `StreamWriter` declaration to where it's used. Not sure if the OS already opens it in the declaration and then deleting fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreamWriter object that use filename is delete and create the file. You are getting this error because you call File.Delete() method before RW.Close(). You can write your code as follow.

```
        string FileName = @"C:\project\userandPassword.txt";
        if (File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            //delete the file if exists .
            File.Delete(FileName);

        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter RW = new StreamWriter(FileName);
            UserName user = new UserName();

            Console.WriteLine("please enter your new user name");
            user.Newuser = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("please enter your password");
            user.Newpassword = Console.ReadLine();
            RW.WriteLine(user.Newuser);
            RW.WriteLine(user.Newpassword);
            RW.Close();
        }
```